# How to access parent.document elements using JQuery in firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox

For example:

```
$(elementid,top.document).attr(attributeName)
```

or

```
$(elementid,parent.document).attr(attributeName)
```

works in IE or Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox.

Does anyone know what the firefox equivalence is?

Thanks!

Comment: Both top.document and parent.document work int Firefox. What did you put as elementid and attributeName?

Comment: I think normally it works, just like using $(elemmentid), but i was accessing from a html file loaded by an iframe and don't have access to the outside html.
it is like:
<html>
<a id = "outsideA"/>
<iframe>
   <html>
     <a id ="insideA" onclick="accessOutsideA()"/>
   </html>
</iframe>
</html>

Answer (score 76, accepted):

What about:

```
window.parent.$(elementid).attr(attributeName);
```

Comment: window.parent.getElementById(elementid)[attributeName] for no jQuery

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
$("#myid", top.document);
```

or

```
$("#myid", parent.document.body);
```

[Ref](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/5997ef4a60a123af)

Comment: $("#myid", parent.window.document)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(elementid,window.parent.frames[0].document).attr(attributeName)
```

What are you trying to achieve - perhaps giving the question in context will get you better solutions.

Comment: it doesn't work. I was trying to access an element outside an iframe from a click function called inside that iframe.

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget `document.domain = "yourdomain.com"` before running `$(selector, parent.document)` because I ran into "access denied" issues just like `location.href` for iframes