# Get meta tags of parent from iframe using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-parsing

I have an HTML file with the following content

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

<meta content="desc goes here" name="description">
<meta content="auth name" name="author">
<title>builder 1.0</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://domain.com/a.html" name="cxsideframe" scrolling:'no';="" id="frame1" style="overflow:hidden;">
</iframe>
</body></html>
```

The content of a.html is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>builder v1.0</title>


<body>
<img src="http://example.com/images/01._V397411194_.png" style="display:none" alt=""/>
<img src="http://example.com/images/V386942464_.gif" style="display:none" alt="" />
</body></html>
```

I need to know a method to get  the contents of meta tags and image lists of parent page html from the parent page using jQuery or javascript.

```
$('meta[name=author]').attr("content");       does not work for me
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1133526/921204 - Replace `$(elementid).attr(attributeName)` with `$('meta[name=author]').attr("content")`

Comment: @techfoobar it returns undefined

Comment: which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan 1.7.1

Comment: @Zubin As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes. change the `attr` with `prop` and check

Comment: Since it is a call from another domain, it wont work. a.html is in another domain

Answer (score -1):

You can use document.getElementsByTagNames, and then manipulate the array returned

```
 var metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
 var imagesOnPage = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

Comment: Since it is from iframe, I get a blank result